# Python 2.7; Downloaded a file and attempted to overwrite an .mp3, receiving: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'audio.mp3'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7
Windows 8

I downloaded a file from the internet using:

```
testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve(str(audio_link), "audio.mp3")
```

audio_link is a format something like:

```
http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/R02/R0203700.mp3
```

The program should be writing to an existing audio.mp3 in the working directory with the url from the above code. It was working properly until I made some changes to the program that don't seem to have to do with the problem.

Specifically, the problem shows:

```
File "D:\Paul\projects\spelling test\python.py", line 105, in get_pronunciation
testfile.retrieve(str(audio_link), "audio.mp3")#open the link as a saved file; creates file; maybe overwrites old??
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 249, in retrieve
  tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'audio.mp3'
```

get_pronunciation is a function, and I *think* that tfp is built in to the testfile usage.

My cmd has no chmod (I tried chmod 777 /working/directory/blah/) and, even as administrator, it is not recognized as a command.

I also tried to go to the properties of the working directory through **windows explorer**>right-click>**properties**>**security** tab>**edit**>click on **Users**>check-mark **full control**.

Help? Regards.

Comment: Chmod? Aren't you in Windows?

Comment: Your script should overwrite the mp3 file each time, I suggest adding a full path to ensure you know where it will be written to. If the directory already has a folder called `audio.mp3`, this would cause error 13.

Comment: @Idos I am in Windows, but I've seen suggestions to use it and also read a way to install it on my system, which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MartinEvans Yes, I do happen to keep the file and attempt to rewrite it using that command. Do you have any suggestions on how to get rid of it or can I just use os.remove() ?

Comment: @PaulNgo did you try running python "as an administrator"?